# how to prepare acid washed sand for disruption of cell wall and the amount required for disruption

Tags: synthesis

the sample is a mixed sample of maize(yellow and white) undergoing fermentation. while conducting an analysis for  extraction of crude enzyme.Acid washed sand was required for the liberation of enzyme trapped in the cell

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is with a sintered glass filter funnel. Place the sand in the funnel, add the acid (1M HCl or H2SO4 will do for this), stir it around then apply the suction, Turn off the suction, add clean water, stir it around then apply the suction again. Repeat the wash a couple of times then dry under suction, pour the sand out of funnel and oven dry.